# Cannot see google storage buckets when connecting to VM through SFTP

Tags: linux, storage, sftp, gcloud

Let's call sftp user Bob. On the VM itself, I can see and access the bucket no problem. Permissions are bob:bob. But when connecting via sftp directory buckets don't even show.

fstab config:
Bucket /mnt/google-buckets/bob/Bucket gcsfuse rw,allow_others,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,user

Pertinent sftp config:

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User Bob
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin no
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PermitTTY no

The google storage bucket is mounted under bob/Bucket. From an ssh session a directory I can see the 'Bucket' folder:

bob# pwd
/mnt/google-buckets/bob

bob# ls -alh
drwxr-xr-x 1 bob bob 0 Oct 20 18:19 Bucket
-rwx------ 1 bob bob 0 Oct 20 18:05 retest.txt

I can connect no problem to sftp as user bob. It puts me in bob's home directory:
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /mnt/google-buckets/bob

But the Bucket directory doesn't appear:
sftp> ls -alh
-rwx------    ? 1003     1004           0B Oct 20 11:05 retest.txt

Any help would be appreciated!